# Facebook - Add Page Tab

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

trying to transfer my ap to main profile on facebook:
https://apps.facebook.com/gavinwynne/

did the fix as button is missing now
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=370018013025352&next=https://www.gavinwynne.co.uk/facebook/index.html/

but get an error = 
Add page tab
This application does not support integration with your profile.

Any idea guys ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding App to Fanpage - "Not supported"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005003/adding-app-to-fanpage-not-supported)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Page Tab as platform

Official documentation can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Answer (score 0):

setup a tab in application settings with a reachable url

Comment: thanks, that worked, but when applying page tab to facebook page get error:- 404 Not found

Comment: hmmm looks like it has applied it. Only problem now is that it is in pages i have sent up that i cant delete. I actually just want it to load in my main profile ?