# Adding App to Fanpage - "Not supported"

Tags: facebook

I followed the directions on facebook to add my app (which is a tab) to my fanpage:

> "Facebook Page administrators can add your app directly to their Page by navigating to the following URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL, where YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_URL can be found in your app settings."

But I got this message:

> "This application does not support integration with your profile."

The names of the app and page are not exactly the same. But the name of the app has a "-" in the name - a fan page name cannot have a "-" in the name, so I cannot rename it to the same name.

What can I do? Who can help me?

Comment: are you sure that you substituted the correct `APP_ID` and `NEXT` parameters for that URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Tab to facebook page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370636/adding-a-tab-to-facebook-page)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to add an app to your fanpage you need to fill in the "**Page Tab**" section With your site url

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your app isn't configured to actually provide a page tab - check the 'Page Tab' section of your app's settings to make sure you've configured it correctly.

Comment: There is no longer a 'Page Tab' section of your app settings

Comment: Are you sure? there is for my apps - click 'Add Platform' - 'Page Tab' if your app hasn't already got settings for a page tab integration

Comment: I've made a blog post about my whole ordeal if anyone will find it helpful: http://visionsofsplendor.tumblr.com/post/84453644133/creating-a-facebook-page-tab-app-a-lot-more-difficult

Comment: You may also find this document useful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: I didn't include this doc in my blog post because it's pretty much useless. It has Steps A and B and kind of misses and important part in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

## You must choose "**PAGE TAB**" in the dialog ! ! !

see the TUTORIAL here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287477/2377343

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has recently made changes to its developer interface and specially the App Dashboard. Hence it might be a bit tricky to find out how to configure the Page Tab. Refer the following tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Comment: This page hasn't been updated in a while either. See where it says to upload your page tab image - that is no longer done in the same area.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your App Settings, then Basic and add a platform as page tab. Provide a URL with https, even if you don't have it, just to test. Then run this page and you can successfully add your app to the page tab.